# magento show navigation item by product count

Tags: magento-1.9

In Magento category(Product list) page, categories and attribute options are showing at left sidebar. I want to sort these items by product counts.Please anyone can explain that in which file i have to write code ?
Thanks

Comment: Hello, any one please can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code once. Change your category ID.

```
<?php
    $cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3)->getChildrenCategories();
?>
 <ul>   
    <?php
    $resourcearray = array();
    foreach($cats as $category): 
    $proCnt = $category->getProductCount();
    $proName = $category->getName();
    $proUrl = $category->getUrl();
    array_push($resourcearray, array('count' => $proCnt, 'name' => $proName,'url' => $proUrl));
    ?>
    <?php endforeach; 
    ksort($resourcearray);
    ?>
    <?php foreach($resourcearray as $val): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $val['url'] ?>"><?php echo $val['name'] ?>(<?php echo $val['count'] ?>)</a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
```